# Want to remove the scroll bar from text area?

Tags: css, textarea

i made the text area and i want  that when my text exceeds the width of text area then instead of creating scroll bar it should simply increase the width of text area how can i do this here is the html code and also the css which i am applying on this please suggest me some thing.i am trying to make this text area work like facebook comment box ?

```
<style>
.textarticle
 {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  width:600px;
  max-width:600px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 140px;
  border:1px solid E7DBDB;
  border-radius:5px;
  overflow:none;
 }
</style>

<html>
 <textarea class="textarticle" name="textarticl" placeholder="Enter Article">
</html>
```

Comment: It's `overflow:hidden`, not `overflow:none`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier i tried this but this only removes the scroll bar it does not increase the height ?

Comment: i am trying to make this text area work like facebook comment box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JoshCrozier is right that you want `overflow:hidden`. To make the textarea automatically expand in height you need a little help from a JQuery plugin. A useful one is Jack Moore's [autosize.js](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/autosize.js).

Just call `$('textarea').autosize();` and you're good to go.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8N3tY/) to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 3):

Add overflow:auto

textarea { overflow: auto; }

Answer (score 0):

hiding the scrollbars without affecting scrolling I think is the intended behavior: https://blog.logrocket.com/hide-scrollbar-without-impacting-scrolling-css

so for example:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar{
 display: none;
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar{
 display: none;
}
```